# How to define a double productory

Tags: products

I have the following expression (which I find in the [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4679), Eq. (136).)

$$\delta=\prod_{\mu, \nu =0}^{1}\left[\left(a_{1} + \left(-1 \right)^\mu a_{2} + \left(-1\right)^{\nu}a_{3}\right)^2 - 1\right], \tag{1}$$

where, If I understand correctly, the $\prod_{\mu, \nu =0}^{1}$ implies a double productory. Then, my question is: **how to expand the above expression**?

In an attempt to answer my own question I try the following:

$$\delta =\prod_{\mu, \nu =0}^{1}\left[\left(a_{1} + \left(-1 \right)^\mu a_{2} + \left(-1\right)^{\nu}a_{3}\right)^2 - 1\right] \\
= \prod_{\mu =0}^{1} \prod_{\nu =0}^{1}\left[\left(a_{1} + \left(-1 \right)^\mu a_{2} + \left(-1\right)^{\nu}a_{3}\right)^2 - 1\right]. \tag{2}$$

Then, I expand the productory in $\mu$, hence I obtain

$$\delta=\prod_{\nu =0}^{1} \left[\left(a_{1} + \left(-1 \right)^0 a_{2} + \left(-1\right)^{\nu}a_{3}\right)^2 - 1\right]  \left[\left(a_{1} + \left(-1 \right)^1 a_{2} + \left(-1\right)^{\nu}a_{3}\right)^2 - 1\right]. \tag{3}$$

Now I expand the productory in $\nu$, obtaining

$$\delta=\left[\left(a_{1} + \left(-1 \right)^0 a_{2} + \left(-1\right)^{0}a_{3}\right)^2 - 1\right]  \left[\left(a_{1} + \left(-1 \right)^1 a_{2} + \left(-1\right)^{0}a_{3}\right)^2 - 1\right] \\\times \left[\left(a_{1} + \left(-1 \right)^0 a_{2} + \left(-1\right)^{1}a_{3}\right)^2 - 1\right]  \left[\left(a_{1} + \left(-1 \right)^1 a_{2} + \left(-1\right)^{1}a_{3}\right)^2 - 1\right].\tag{4}$$

**Is my above procedure correct?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks good to me.